# Fetch data from API CLEARBIT with GOOGLE APP SCRIPTS -

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch-api, urlfetch

I was trying to fetch data from Clearbit API and I get this message : " **Exception: The parameters (String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for UrlFetchApp.fetch.**"

Before writing this post I tried to search online but couldn't find the answer.

I share with you my code :

```
function linkedInUrl(domain) {
  let url = `https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=${domain}`
  const api_keys = ""
  const header = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + api_keys}
  }
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,header,options)
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

return "https://www.linkedin.com/"+data.linkedin.handle
}


function techUsed(domain) {
  let url = `https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=${domain}`
  const api_keys = ""
  const header = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + api_keys}
  }
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,header,options)
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
tech = ""
for(let i = 0; i < data.tech.length; i++) {
  tech += data.tech[i] +","
}
return tech
}
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
function linkedInUrl(domain) {
  let url = `https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=${domain}`
  const api_keys = ""
  const header = {
     method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + api_keys}
  }
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var res
  fetch(url,header,options)           //api for the get request
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('response',data))

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments of `fetch(url, params)` are `url` and `params`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. So, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
  let url = `https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=${domain}`
  const api_keys = ""
  const header = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + api_keys}
  }
  options = {muteHttpExceptions: true};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,header,options)
```

#### To:

```
let url = `https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=${domain}`;
const api_keys = "###"; // Please set your access token.
options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_keys },
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, your `api_keys` is valid value for using the API. Please be careful about this.
- Unfortunately, I cannot know the response value from the API you want to use. So, if your script below `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);` occurs an error, please provide the sample value. By this, I would like to confirm your script.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Mohamed Necib About `It worked thank you`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer